# Is it possible to keep the fading background on the node without showing the back of the drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, tikz-node, tikz-fadings

I have just discovered the fading library of the software and I find it curious that I have not found an easy method to not show the back drawing, that is to say that the background of the node is solid but keeping the fading.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {fadings,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill [color=orange,path fading=north] (-1.5,-1) rectangle (5.5,7.75);
\draw[-] (-0,0,0)--(4.25,0,0);

\draw[line width=0.5pt, ](-0,3)-- (4,3) ;
\draw[line width=0.5pt, ](-0,7)-- (4,7) ;
\draw[|-|] (0.5,0)-- (0.5,3) node[midway,fill=pgftransparent!1, inner sep=1pt] {Altura };
\draw[|-|, ] (1.25,0)-- (1.25,7) node[midway,path fading=north,, inner sep=1pt] {Altura};                                                               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to keep the fading on the node without showing the back of the drawing?

I have just discovered the fading library of the software and I find it curious that I have not found an easy method to not show the back drawing, that is to say that the background of the node is solid but keeping the fading.

[image: Image with the wrong fading background and image with the solid fading background]

Image with the wrong fading background and image with the solid fading background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to split the line that goes through the node. You could also try something like "inverse clipping" to clip the shape of the node from the line, but this is not trivial.

I would rather suggest that you first draw a path (which is essentially a line that is not drawn) to position the node at the center of it and then draw the lines from the start coordinate of the path to the node as well as from the node to the end coordinate of the path. I think this is the most straigh-forward approach to this.

You could create a `\pic` to make typesetting a bit easier:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzset{
    pics/|-| with node/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{|-| with node/.cd, #1}
            \path 
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/|-| with node/from} coordinate (-from) 
                -- \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/|-| with node/to} coordinate (-to) 
                node[midway, inner sep=1pt] (-node) 
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/|-| with node/node text}};
            \draw[|-] (-from) -- (-node);
            \draw[-|] (-node) -- (-to);
        }
    },
    |-| with node/from/.initial={(0,0)},
    |-| with node/to/.initial={(0,0)},
    |-| with node/node text/.initial={}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \fill[color=orange, path fading=north] 
        (-1.5,-1) rectangle (5.5,7.75);

    \draw[-] (0,0) -- (4.25,0);
    \draw[line width=0.5pt] (0,3) -- (4,3);
    \draw[line width=0.5pt] (0,7) -- (4,7);
    
    \path (0.5,0) coordinate (from) -- (0.5,3) coordinate (to) 
        node[midway, inner sep=1pt] (node) {Altura};
    \draw[|-] (from) -- (node);
    \draw[-|] (node) -- (to);

    \pic {|-| with node={
        from={(1.25,0)}, to={(1.25,7)}, node text={Altura}
    }};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Maybe nice to know: The `\pic` can also be used with horizontal or even diagonal lines:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzset{
    pics/|-| with node/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{|-| with node/.cd, #1}
            \path 
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/|-| with node/from} coordinate (-from) 
                -- \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/|-| with node/to} coordinate (-to) 
                node[midway, inner sep=1pt] (-node) 
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/|-| with node/node text}};
            \draw[|-] (-from) -- (-node);
            \draw[-|] (-node) -- (-to);
        }
    },
    |-| with node/from/.initial={(0,0)},
    |-| with node/to/.initial={(0,0)},
    |-| with node/node text/.initial={}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \fill[color=orange, path fading=north] 
        (-5,1) rectangle (5,-3);

    \pic {|-| with node={
        from={(-4,0)}, to={(4,0)}, node text={Anchura}
    }};
        
    \pic {|-| with node={
        from={(-4,-2)}, to={(4,-1)}, node text={Longitud}
    }};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Jasper thank you very much, the \pic option it is tthe option of 2 is the best by far.